# python sending via socket a variable

Tags: python

```
a = 911111100000
while a < 911111100050:
    lMDN = str(a)
    print lMDN
    sock.send("PAGE lMDN\r\n" )
    page_data = ""
    page_string = ""
    while page_data != "\n":
        page_data = sock.recv(1)
        page_string = page_string + page_data
    print page_string
    a += 1
```

how do i correct this, lMDN is coming as 'a' in the logs. I'm new to python.
     sample output:
     911111100042
    550 Error, Invalid Pager ID

Comment: Please format the code to a more readable block. Use the `Code Sample` button in the textbox (the `<$>` button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably need to do this:

```
while a < 911111100050:
    print a
    sock.send("PAGE %d\r\n" % a)
```

You are not sending the page number but the PAGE 1LDM string in your socket.

But as I don't know what are you trying to achieve this is mostly a wild guess.

Comment: Then please mark the answer as correct, so that the question is closed.